# Copying the reference to a line or a symbol in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am wondering is there a way to do in Visual Studio what can be done with the feature "[Copying the reference to a line or a symbol](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/cutting-copying-and-pasting.html#d992468e108)" in PyCharm?

What the feature does: When the cursor is on an identifier in a code file, the full name of that identifier is copied to the clipboard. When the cursor is not on an identifier, the name of the source code file and the current line number is copied to the clipboard.